# How to save c++ object into a xml file and restore back?

Tags: c++, xml, serialization

How to save c++ object into a xml file and restore back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) and [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/) can both do this.  The libs11n manual (available [here](http://s11n.net/download/)) has an extensive comparison of the two.

As Tobias said, the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/serialization.html) has good background information.

Answer (score 7):

Boost's [serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) might be implementing a lot of the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Serialization is a complex topic which is probably too much for a simple answer on SO. Unfortunately with C++, you don't get it for free as in other languages.

See the [C++ faq lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html) or [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for a start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any direct way of achieving this. You can write separate methods to serialize and de-seriealize methods in which individual data members of the object need to be written and extracted from the file.