# C++: Saving the class object in archived format which is having char * attributes and read it back from file

Tags: c++

Assume I have a class

```
class A
{
 char *attr1,*attr2;
public:
 . . .
};
```

How to save the object of this class to file in a binary format and read it back?

Thanks.

Comment: @Manjunath: What did you end up doing? Please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about serialization. For example the [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library. They have a nice definition:

> Here, we use the term "serialization"
>   to mean the reversible deconstruction
>   of an arbitrary set of C++ data
>   structures to a sequence of bytes.
>   Such a system can be used to
>   reconstitute an equivalent structure
>   in another program context. Depending
>   on the context, this might used
>   implement object persistence, remote
>   parameter passing or other facility.
>   In this system we use the term
>   "archive" to refer to a specific
>   rendering of this stream of bytes.
>   This could be a file of binary data,
>   text data, XML, or some other created
>   by the user of this library.

That said, such a solution is the 5-kg hammer that solves most serialization problems. It may be the case that you need something far simpler. For example, if you object only consists of a few `char*` attributes you can save it in a simpler way. A general solution, however, would allow you flexibility in case your object gets more complex in the future.

Comment: I dont have any problem in saving the objects. But reading back from a file is bit tricky as I guess :) I am using:
"ofstream outbal("fileName", ios::out | ios::binary);"
"outbal.write((char *) &obj, sizeof(classA));"

But not getting how can i read it back from file :(

Comment: @Manjunath You are writing out the pointers to the strings, but not the strings they are pointing to.

Comment: @Manjunath: the serialization library gives you tools to both write and read back the data, of course!

Answer (score 2):

For efficient, fast and extensible binary serialization format, take a look at [Google protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/).

Answer (score 0):

### You might want to try xml

---

Instead of Binary, You might want to try xml.

The (**field=value**) format is very easily parsed back too.

> http://cppxmlobj.sourceforge.net/

Also checkout this Qustion:

> [How to save c++ object into a xml file and restore back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974815/how-to-save-c-object-into-a-xml-file-and-restore-back)

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: Signatures are discouraged, see e.g. here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed